# VS 2013 MVC ASP.NET Identity default project and logging in using Google

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using the default MVC template in VS 2013 that allows logging in using google. I'm attempting to modify the program so that I don't have to enter a username for the site. So I added a google image link where the Login in was. I want this to go straight to the Account/ExternalLogin page and automatically use google as the source.

When I use the following it fails to find the page:

```
<li>@Html.ActionImage("ExternalLogin", "Account", null, "~/Content/Red-signin_Long_base_20dp.png", "Google", new { provider="Google", returnUrl="" })</li>
```

However, when I use the following it finds the page:

```
<li>@Html.ActionImage("Login", "Account", null, "~/Content/Red-signin_Long_base_20dp.png", "Google", new { provider="Google", returnUrl="" })</li>
```

This seems like an MVC question, but why can't it find the ExternalLogin function in the Account controller but it can find the Login function in the same controller?

Comment: Is the `ExternalLogin` method private?

Comment: Nope, it's public because it's called when you click the default MVC project's Google button on the Login page. I'm just trying to skip the Login page and go straight to Google when the user clicks the Google image link I have on the homepage. That Google button the default mvc project makes uses the following where the action variable is "ExternalLogin": using (Html.BeginForm(action, "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl })). So it's being called from another page but I can't figure out why I can't call it in my link.

Comment: Can you post the exact error and also your `ActionImage` extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `ExternalLogin()` method...

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
```

`Account/ExternalLogin` will only respond to POST requests. It looks like your `ActionImage()` helper is using GET, which is why it is getting a 404. In addition, the call requires a valid anti-forgery token.

To submit a POST with the required parameters and anti-forgery token, take a look at what Microsoft has done with the Logout link (`~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml`) and adapt it for your needs...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "googleForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Hidden("provider", "Google")
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('googleForm').submit()">
        <img src="~/Content/Red-signin_Long_base_20dp.png" />
    </a>
}
```

Comment: I see now. The Login() method that was getting called normally was the Get one that didn't have the ValidatAntiForgeryToken. Thanks for this!